# Issue with Fiddler and the PowerShell ISE

Tags: fiddler, powershell-ise

I can verify that some PowerShell script code that makes REST calls from the PowerShell ISE evades Fiddler (REST calls). Everything works from both a PowerShell console session and from the PowerShell ISE. It is just that when I invoke the commands from the PowerShell ISE, I see *nothing* in Fiddler.

Is there a specialized proxy setting for the PowerShell ISE that I don't know about?

PowerShell Info:
PowerShell v3/v4 on Windows 8.1

Fiddler Info:
Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.4.9.8)
Built: Thursday, December 18, 2014

64-bit AMD64, VM: 221.00mb, WS: 248.00mb
.NET 4.0.30319.0 WinNT 6.3.9600.0

Running ELEVATED on: :8888
Listening to: All Adapters
Gateway: No Gateway